# django admin tools and grappelli together

Tags: django-grappelli, django-admin-tools

**Is it possible to have django grappeli and django admin tools menu running together?**

I've installed both, but only see grappeli or admin tools (depending on order in INSTALLED_APPS).

I found old source that says django admin tools and grappelli work together http://code.google.com/p/django-grappelli-admin-tools/ , but given documentation doesn't help.

Comment: What parts of admin-tools are you trying to use?

Comment: I was trying to use admin tools menu with grappelli.

Comment: Couple ways to approach that -- the one I tend to use is copy the functions from Mezzanine http://mezzanine.jupo.org -- specifically the admin header at https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/master/mezzanine/core/templates/admin/includes/dropdown_menu.html (you'll need to reverse a couple vars but relatively easy)

Comment: @Alvin...  I'm also interested in doing this;  I really just want to create a dashboard type of interface for my application.  I don't suppose you can elaborate any more on your comment.  Or do you know of any blog posts, etc.  My googlin' doesn't turn up much.

Comment: It a bit hard to find enough time for this, but if someone would start a app project for admintools + grappelli I would gladly join it.